# Is it okay if the row references in the INDEX(MATCH) formula are distant from the array?

Tags: excel

Say, for instance, you type in

```
=INDEX('[ANOTHER FILE.xlsx]1'!$B$5:$Z$10,
        MATCH($A5,'[ANOTHER FILE.xlsx]1'!$A$5:$A$10,0),
        MATCH(B$3,'[ANOTHER FILE.xlsx]1'!$B$3:$Z$3,0)
      )
```

Here, I'm worried that `B3:Z3` and `B5:Z10` are one row apart. Is this an acceptable setting?

In my opinion it is, because after all `INDEX(MATCH)` retrieves the corresponding `row*column` number in the matrix, so as long as you provide the correct row and column numbers, the corresponding correct number will be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is acceptable. The only thing you need to worry about is that the MATCH produces the correct number for the lookup you want to achieve. Where that number comes from is totally irrelevant.